# Javascript add a PHP file

Tags: php, javascript

```
var editing  = false;

if (document.getElementById && document.createElement) {
    var butt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var buttext = document.createTextNode('Ready!');
    butt.appendChild(buttext);
    butt.onclick = saveEdit;
}

function catchIt(e) {
    if (editing) return;
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement) return;
    if (!e) var obj = window.event.srcElement;
    else var obj = e.target;
    while (obj.nodeType != 1) {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    if (obj.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || obj.tagName == 'A') return;
    while (obj.nodeName != 'P' && obj.nodeName != 'HTML') {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    if (obj.nodeName == 'HTML') return;
    var x = obj.innerHTML;
    var y = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    var z = obj.parentNode;
    z.insertBefore(y,obj);
    z.insertBefore(butt,obj);
    z.removeChild(obj);
    y.value = x;
    y.focus();
    editing = true;
}

function saveEdit() {
    var area = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA')[0];
    var y = document.createElement('P');
    var z = area.parentNode;
    y.innerHTML = area.value;
    z.insertBefore(y,area);
    z.removeChild(area);
    z.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]);
    editing = false;
}

document.onclick = catchIt;
```

This code is a quick edit and I want to add a PHP script that will UPDATE my database base on the changes on the text.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest studying [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

There are also JavaScript libraries out there that make AJAX easy to use. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is one.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [Ajax](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) for that.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript works on the client side, so it is not possible to add a PHP script, however you can use AJAX for this purpose, from which you can interact with your database.

For this you would have to make a separate PHP script that you can call from your JavaScript function without reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use AJAX, yes, as said above. I'm going to tell you, it's a rough trip to learn. But it can be made pretty easy to use if you're willing to learn a small bit of commands. [Pipes](https://github.com/wise-penny/pipes) is what I use. I am completely sure it will work for you. Here's an example:

```
post_html = "<b headers='method:post;' ajax='db.php' insert='success' query='addName=" + obj.name + "'>Click me to add Your Name to the DB!</b>";
post_html += "<h1 id='success'></h1>";
```

The clickable HTML is the  tag and the second line of HTML will get the "echo" or whatever print format you're using from db.php. That's simply Pipes!